# "Full outer join" using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, sql, full-outer-join

I don't mind using a library to solve this problem, especially if it simplifies the code.

I've got some data like this:

```
 [{source: 'b', foo: 'bar'},
   {source:'d', foo: 'baz'}]
```

And I've got another array like this:

```
['b', 'c', 'e']
```

I'd like to process these two arrays and get this as output:

```
 [{source: 'b', foo: 'bar'},
    {source: 'c', foo: 'someDefaultValue'}, 
    {source:'d', foo: 'baz'}, 
    {source: 'e', foo: 'someDefaultValue'}]
```

To elaborate, if data is in the first array, it should remain in the result.  If data is in the second array, it should appear in the result with default values.  I want the result to be sorted by `source`.

In SQL terms, I'd refer to this as a "Full Outer Join on the source column."  I'm finding it difficult to write code in JavaScript that works this way.  How would I get the result given the two inputs?

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this

- Create a `Map` with source as key,
- Initialize `final` with `arr1` values, if you don't need immutability you can directly push on `arr1`
- Loop over arr2 and check if value is not available in mapper, push in `final` with default value
- Sort based on source

```js
let arr1 =  [{source: 'b', foo: 'bar'}, {source:'d', foo: 'baz'}]
let arr2 = ['b', 'c', 'e']
let final = [...arr1]
let mapper = new Map(arr1.map(v=>[v.source,v.source]))

arr2.forEach(val=>{
  if(!mapper.has(val)){
    final.push({source:val, foo:'default'})
  }
})

final.sort((a,b)=> a.source.localeCompare(b.source))

console.log(final)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could take two arrays of object and a key on which the join is taking place an collect all values in a map.

```js
function fullOuterJoin(left, right, on) {
    const
        getV = o => o[on],
        getMap = (m, o) => m.set(getV(o), Object.assign(m.get(getV(o)) || {}, o));

    return Array
        .from(left.reduce(getMap, right.reduce(getMap, new Map)).values())
        .sort((a, b) => getV(a).localeCompare(getV(b)));
}

var left = [{ source: 'b', foo: 'bar' }, { source:'d', foo: 'baz' }],
    source = ['b', 'c', 'e'],
    right = source.map(source => ({ source, foo: 'someDefaultValue' })),
    result = fullOuterJoin(left, right, 'source');

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: output sequence is not properly sorted

Comment: just add a sorting.

Answer (score 1):

```
arr1 = [{source: 'b', foo: 'bar'},
 {source:'d',  foo: 'baz'}]

arr2 = ['b', 'c', 'e']
```

It's simple

```
arr2.map((x)=>{!arr1.map((x)=>x.source).includes(x)?arr1.push({source:x,foo:'someDefaultValue'}):null})
```

Result is arr1

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you want to combine the result into a new array instead of modifying inputs.

- Index source values from `array 1`
- Iterate `array 2` and check whether the corresponding source exists. If yes skip it and if not add one.

Optionally, you may sort the result by `source` if you need to.

Here you go:

```js
let data1 = [{ source: 'b', foo: 'bar' }, { source: 'd', foo: 'baz' }];
let data2 = ['b', 'c', 'e'];
let indices = [];
let data3 = [...data1];
data1.forEach(token => indices.push(token.source));
data2.forEach(token => {
    if (!indices.includes(token)) {
        data3.push({ source: token, foo: 'default' })
    }
});
console.log(data3);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure there's any super easy way of doing this without just writing it up yourself.

```js
const data = [
    {source: 'b', foo: 'bar'},
    {source: 'd', foo: 'baz'}
];
const other = ['b', 'c', 'e'];
const defaultValue = 'someDefaultValue';

const joined = [...data];
other.forEach(source => {
    if (!data.some(item => item.source === source)) {
        joined.push({source, foo: defaultValue});
    }
});

console.log(joined);
```

Comment: The output is not in order, though I suppose I could figure that out on my own.

Answer (score 0):

So say that arrays are called `first` and `second` in the order which you wrote.

then I think this is the solution

```
let result = [...first];
for(let letter of second) {
    let contains = false;
    for(let obj of first) {
        if(obj.source == letter) {
            contains = true;
            result = [...result, obj]
        }
    }
    if(!contains) result = [...result, {source: letter, bar: "defaultValue"}] 
} 
result = result.sort((a, b) => a.source < b.source ? -1 : (a.source == b.source ? 0 : 1));
result = Array.from(new Set(result))
```

Comment: I just copy all objects from your first array into `result`, then I check for every letter in second array (your array of letters), if they are as value in some object from first array, if so, copy it into, if not, create new object with defaultValue in `bar` property, then sort `result` by `source` property and then remove duplicates

Answer (score 0):

I didn't want to go too complex, and didn't want to use newer syntax, but here's more of a helper function, more generic for people to use and expand on. Hopefully is straight forward enough. This only sorts properly for string values. It is immutable so doesn't change the original arrays.

```js
var arrLeft = [
  {source: 'b', foo: 'bar'},
  {source:'d', foo: 'baz'}
];

var arrRight = ['b', 'c', 'e'];

var fullJoin = function(arr1, arr2, key, defaultVal) {
  // Create deep copy array of the left side to include all...
  var newArr = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(arr1));
  var newEle;
  // Loop through right side to make sure to include all
  for (var i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
    // If it doesn't exist in left side, add it with default value
    if (!newArr.find(function(p) { return p[key] === arr2[i]; })) {
      newEle = {};
      newEle[key] = arr2[i];
      newEle.foo = defaultVal;
      newArr.push(newEle);
    }
  }
  // Sort on key alphabetically
  return newArr.sort(function(a, b) {
    var sourceA = a[key].toLowerCase();
    var sourceB = b[key].toLowerCase();
    switch(true) {
      case sourceA > sourceB:
        return 1;
      case sourceA < sourceB:
        return -1;
      default:
        return 0;
    }
  });
};
// Call like so
console.log(fullJoin(arrLeft,arrRight,'source','somedefault'));
```

Comment: There are more elegant ways of course but since this question is about mimicking sql I figured I'd offer a more procedural code snippet for folks who prefer code that many developers can read and understand easily.